# MongoDB retryable writes in unordered bulk operation

Tags: mongodb

I am building a bulk operation for my application and it only consist of single-document write operations.

However, I need each operation to have mongodb "retryable writes" enabled correctly.

So I am wondering if an unordered bulk write works just fine for it or wether it only works with an ordered bulk operation (which would be less efficient) ?

Beside, I have correctly added the retryable write option in my connection string.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the operations can be retried in an unordered operation.  From the MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/):

> Bulk write operations that only consist of the single-document write operations. A retryable bulk operation can include any combination of the specified write operations but cannot include any multi-document write operations, such as updateMany.

Note that the write is only retried a single time, so the application still needs to be able to deal with write failures.

Comment: They also add for unordered bulks : "If an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations, MongoDB will continue to process remaining write operations in the list."
But an error beyond retrying the write at least once ?